# Catch "IndexOutOfBoundsException" in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, exception, error-handling, swift2

I got this code in my Playground:

```
func throwsError() throws{
    var x = [1,2]
    print(x[3])
}

func start(){

    do{
        try throwsError()

    }
    catch let unknown{
        "unknown: \(unknown)"
    }
}

start()
```

So obviously the`'throwsError` function throws an error:

> **Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION**

Is there a way to catch this?
I read online to write a subscript for the Array class that always checks for range but the issue is bigger:
Am I not capable to just catch anything?

Comment: Exceptions and errors are different things, you can't catch exceptions in Swift.

Comment: would be awesome if we can write error handlers like we can write completion handlers and have them work in tandem with the do try catch method.

Comment: I think you can : [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: The catching of exception we know from Obj-C has never worked. It has the same problems as in C++, usually leaves lots of memory without deallocating and lots of internal states corrupted. Any exception that goes through Cocoa/CocoaTouch APIs corrupts application UI, for example. That's why Apple was always strongly opposed against using exception and it started using `NSErrors`. Don't try to catch exception. If you get an exception, find the cause and solve it. Don't catch it. Swift can't catch exceptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift, you can't `catch` anything. You can only catch *errors* thrown with the `throw` statement in other Swift code or errors, of type NSError set by called Objective C code.

The default array subscript raises an *exception*, but does not `throw` a Swift *error*, so you cannot use try/catch with it.

See also [this article](http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/09/swift-why-try-and-catch-dont-work-the-way-you-expect/) by Erica Sadun.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own method. Not really elegant, but works.

```
enum ArrayError: ErrorType {
    case OutOfBounds(min: Int, max: Int)
}

extension Array {

    mutating func safeAssign(index:Int, value: Element) throws {

        guard self.count > index && index >= 0 else {
            throw ArrayError.OutOfBounds(min: 0, max: (self.count - 1))
        }

        self[index] = value

    }
}

var myArray : [Float] = [1,2]

do {
    try myArray.safeAssign(1, value: Float(5))
} catch ArrayError.OutOfBounds(let min, let max) {
    print("out of bounds : \(min) => \(max)")
}
```

Comment: Although this would help in my specific case, but I was more interested in the general issue of catching exceptions :)

Comment: Didn't see that :) Anyway you could go and write error handler like the one above for all exceptions :D