# Is there any way to check if `EncodedPath` string is valid for `GMSPath` in GoogleMaps on iOS swift?

Tags: ios, google-maps, exception

I have a code that will display many `Polygon`s on the map, This is my code:

```
let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: path_str)
let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: path)
polygon.geodesic = true

polygon.map = pnlMap
```

This snippet work correct if the `path_str` variable in the correct format.

But if there is an error in the format of `path_str` the app will crash.

I tried the following methods:

```
if let path = GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: path_str) {
    // mycode
}
```

Also:

```
do {
    let path = try GMSMutablePath(fromEncodedPath: path_str)
} catch ()...
```

I didn't reach to any correct solution.

I couldn't find a way to handle this exception.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They fixed this issue in the new: [version 2.1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases#version_21_-_september_22_2016)

> GMSPath initFromEncodedPath now returns nil for invalid input (previously invalid input could result in a crash). ([Issue 10162](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10162).)

Now if the `Encoded Path string` is wrong, the `GMSPath path` variable will be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I too got stuck in such a problem and I am sorry, but there is no way you can check that. I rectified the problem by making sure that the source is sending me correct encoded path.

In my case the crash was occurring cause Objective C was reading \\ as \.
Please check if its the same with you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Actually I just need to add this check for a rich error handling, Because I faced it while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the similar problem. To check on iOS end i just handle the exception and assume if any exception has been raised, this means encoded path is not valid. Here is the code snippet:

```
@try {
        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:pathEncodedString];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid encoded path raised an Exception: %@", exception);
    } @finally {

    }
```

Comment: Do you know the equivalent in `swift` ?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution will not work in swift because it raises an exception, but does not throw a Swift error, so you cannot use try/catch with it. See this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358149/catch-indexoutofboundsexception-in-swift-2
Alternately you can make use of bridging header :)