# Exception Handling in Swift

Tags: swift

```
func errorFunction()
{
    do
    {
        let arrayOfInts: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]

        let i:Int = arrayOfInts[5]
        print(i)
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

At the line where `catch` is written, it gives me warning `'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block`. However, as you can see, the code is going to throw `Index out of bounds` `error`. Also, when I run this code, the code truly does not reach `catch` block.

How can I catch this error?

**Please note that I do not want to catch this exception. Using array was just an example to demonstrate. The reason for asking this question is to understand how to use this `catch` block to catch this or similar exceptions.**

**PS**

1. If you find my question too naive, please feel free to down-vote - but do give an answer for it - I'm really looking for one.

Comment: http://ericasadun.com/2015/06/09/swift-why-try-and-catch-dont-work-the-way-you-expect/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32358759/4601170

Comment: I don't want to save this crash - Array was just an example. I want this runtime error to come and get caught in catch block.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift: *"Swift has no mechanism to catch all arbitrary runtime exceptions."*

Comment: @prabodhprakash You can't catch anything that isn't marked with `throws`. And almost everything marked with `throws` has to be handled in some way or another, using `do...catch`, `try!` or `try?`. In other words, You can never stop a runtime error from happening using `do...catch` nor can you make a method that throws produce a runtime error.

Comment: You are mixing two completely different things. "Index out of bounds" is a *runtime exception* and cannot be `catch`ed. `try/catch` is used to catch *Swift errors* which are thrown with `throw`.

Comment: Trying to catch a runtime exception is not the `swifty` way of doing things, just check if the array count is larger than the index you're trying to get, then handle your error accordingly.

Comment: Does it mean, there is absolutely no simple way to catch such runtime errors?

Comment: @prabodhprakash: Yes, that is what all the referenced answers tell.